# Trying to load new view upon orientation change

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create an application in Xcode that will switch to a new view when the phone is rotated from one orientation to another.

Here is the "switchviewcontroller.h" file code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is the "switchviewcontroller.m" file code:

```
#import "SwitchViewController.h"
#import "secondview.h"

@implementation SwitchViewController

-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender {}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
       (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {    
        [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

}
```

It runs in iPhone simulator with no errors, but, when I rotate it doesn't load the new view. For starters I think I need the app to open in landscape mode, which I don't know how to do, but it still wouldn't work anyway and I think it has something to to with the "initWithNibName" part of the code because I have .xib files and not .nib files. Can anyone help me with these 2 things? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  when pasting code, use the "{ }" button to properly indent it so it gets formatted correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not pushing or presenting anything, you are only init'ing the view.

```
secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

However, its not a good place to show a new view.

If you want to show the same view in a different orientation, try something this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))){

        self.view = landscape;

    }else if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
              (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))){

        self.view = portrait;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Note that `portrait` and `landscape` are UIViews in your UIViewController that you define in your header and connect through Interface Builder.

---

Additionaly, these need to be in **.h** / **.m**:

### .h

```
IBOutlet UIView *portrait;
IBOutlet UIView *landscape;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView portrait;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView landscape;
```

### .m

```
@synthesize portrait,landscape;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't want to sound stupid here but I put your code in and the app behaves exactly the same, I know that your right but I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Well, first of all, I wouldnt push a view when the device rotates, go with the second example. As I stated, you need to define the views in your header, and go through that whole process. I'll update my answer with header code.

Comment: Does this load a new vie or the same view in a new orientation. I am asking this because I want to be able for example (although I'm not specifically doing this) show a picture of a dog in portrait and a highscores table in landscape.

Comment: it will show a new view in a new orientation. The portrait / landscape views can be the same, just rearranged.

Comment: I implemented the code into a new app and the app crashes upon opening

Answer (score 2):

You've got to alloc and init a new view and replace you current viewcontroller's view with the new one.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) {
        UIView *landscapeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        // Setup the landscape view here
        self.view = landscapeView;
        [landscapeView release];
    }
    else {
         UIView *portraitView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        // Setup the portrait view here
        self.view = portraitView;
        [portraitView release];
    }
}
```